# Error:Execution failed for task : ransformException

Tags: android-studio, gradle, duplicates, google-play-services, transform

My gradle Dependency looks like this,

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/Shutterbug-1.0.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/VolleyWithJsonArrayRequest.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/geonames-1.1.12.jar')
    compile files('libs/jdom-1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/kenburnsview-1.0.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
    compile files('libs/multiselectlistpreferencecompat.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.1.jar')    
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
}
```

But when running the application on android studio 1.5, I get the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/analytics/internal/Command$1.class
```

Comment: I am facing same issue, I searched a lot for 4-5 days, but not able to resolve issue. That will be great if you can help me out, if you had resolved this issue.

Comment: can u pls explain how to fix EasyTracker class issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You most likely have duplicates between `libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar` and the `com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0` dependencies.

If you are trying to use the latest SDK (v4), comment/remove the `libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar` line and rebuild.

If you are trying to use the v3 SDK, comment/remove the `com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0` compile line and rebuild.

Source: Latest API docs for Analytics https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

Comment: I have to import EasyTracker from

Comment: I have to import EasyTracker from  com.google.analytics.tracking.android.EasyTracker but i am afraid i couldn't find that specific class in  com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0 or later library , do you have any idea ?

Comment: Now i think like i have fixed the problem by removing the *.jar section  in gradle , thank you :)

Comment: can u pls explain how to fix EasyTracker class issue?

Answer (score 0):

Its very likely a duplicate module com.google.android.gms.analytics.internal

What you can do is exclude the "internal" module like this

compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-analytics-internal'
}